# How to configure system wide proxy with user authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication

I would like to use my LAN's proxy server in Ubuntu Desktop 12.04, but all my attempts have failed.

Here is what I did:

1) I went to System Settings Menu > Network, selected Network Proxy, Manual and entered the proxy address and port for http and https, and clicked Apply system wide. In this dialog box there's no way to enter authentication information (in previous versions of Ubuntu there was a Details button).

2) When I start Firefox a dialog box appears asking for authentication information. I enter "sc\ws662sc" for the user name and "mypass81" for password (and click remember password) and the browser is connected to the internet.

3) After that I go to the Terminal and try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but always get the error "407  Proxy Authentication Required".

5) I edited the config file with:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

to include the user and password info, as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://gcDomain\w66gc:mypass81@pt-tmg.gc.gsc.int:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://gcDomain\w66gc:mypass81@pt-tmg.gc.gsc.int:3128/";
```

Even after I do this Firefox keeps asking for authentication info, and still get the 407 error in apt-get!

Also tried to put the proxy config file inside apt.conf.d (as some suggest for the same problem), but didn't work either. Don't know what else to do...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this issue by using `cntlm`, according to the instructions in:

[How to solve "407 Proxy Authentication Required" error in Ubuntu ?](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.pt/2012/10/microsoft-isa-proxy-authentication-in.html)

Install `cntlm` (for example do `sudo apt-get install cntlm`) then edit the `/etc/cntlm.conf` file to contain:

```
Username   YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
Domain     YOUR_ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN
Password   YOUR_PASSWORD
Proxy      YOUR_PROXY_SERVER_IP_WITH_PORT
NoProxy    LIST_ALL_IP_WITH_NO_PROXY_REQUIREMENT
Listen     SOME_PORT
```

For example:

```
Username   rafa
Domain     awesomeplace
Password   Xtra$trongp4ssw3rD
Proxy      10.18.200.203:8080
Proxy      10.18.200.204:8080
NoProxy    localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*
Listen     8080
```

Still would like to know how it could be done without `cntlm`...